# Правильно ли выделено запятыми слово "пожалуй"?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в предложении:

**Новый объект располагается в, пожалуй, самом красивом городе Абхазии — Новом Афоне.**

Answer (score 4):

**Ответ исправлен.**

Новый объект располагается  **в самом, пожалуй,  красивом** городе Абхазии — Новом Афоне.

1) Нужно переставить вводное слово *пожалуй* (со значением "возможно, может быть, вероятно"), чтобы оно не находилось сразу за предлогом В, причем  **переставить нужно в середину оборота**.

Сравним  примеры:

Это было гнуснейшее местечко на острове и, **пожалуй**, в целом Замоскворечье. [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)]. Это были смутные времена, и, **пожалуй, в самом тяжёлом** положении по сравнению с другими вузами оказался Физтех.  В этих случаях вводное слово **относится ко всему предложению.**

А вот **в самом, пожалуй, известном** произведении писателя «Два капитана» город становится одним из «равноправных героев» романа. [Елена Гиль. 2003.08.20]. В этом примере вводное слово относится **к предложному обороту**.

2) Тире поставлено правильно, это обособленное приложение с пояснительным значением (а именно) в конце предложения.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите отнести "пожалуй" к слову "самый", а не ко всему сочетанию "самый красивый город Абхазии", то порядок слов должен быть такой:

**Новый объект располагается в самом, пожалуй, красивом городе Абхазии — Новом Афоне.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

Была своя задача и в самом, **пожалуй**, грандиозном полотне ― «Покорение Сибири Ермаком». [В. А. Солоухин. Письма из Русского музея (1966)]